# forEach with object properties in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, pug

I have found a few answer regarding this but has not been able to put things together. First day of using Knockout so please let me know if I am thinking about it completely wrong!

I want to represent a list of comments that I have. The comments contain multiple attributes such as {text: ..., score: ..., ...}

I understand that I have a view model

```js
var MatchupViewModel = function(comments) {
    this.comments = ko.observableArray(comments);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MatchupViewModel(comments), document.getElementById("leftchat"));
```

And I understand that the forEach looks somewhat like this:

- in jade (which I am using:

```html
#leftchat.chat(data-bind="forEach: comments")
                .fullMessage
                    .content
                        p.textcontent(data-bind="text: text, visible: text")
                        img.imagecontent(data-bind="visible: isImage, attr={src: url}")
                    .scorecontainer
                        .buttonContainer
                            p.likeButtonMessage(bind-data="click=voteComment(id, true)") &#x25B2
                            p.dislikeButtonMessage(bind-data="click=voteComment(id, false)") &#x25BC
                        p.messageScore(data-bind="text: score")
```

translated to html:

```html
<div id="leftchat" data-bind="forEach: comments" class="chat">
  <div class="fullMessage">
    <div class="content">
      <p data-bind="text: text, visible: text" class="textcontent"></p><img data-bind="visible: isImage, attr={src: url}" class="imagecontent"/>
    </div>
    <div class="scorecontainer">
      <div class="buttonContainer">
        <p bind-data="click=voteComment(id, true)" class="likeButtonMessage">&#x25B2</p>
        <p bind-data="click=voteComment(id, false)" class="dislikeButtonMessage">&#x25BC</p>
      </div>
      <p data-bind="text: score" class="messageScore"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It complains that text is not a function, which is the attribute I had hoped it would have been able to find. How do I work around this?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if we saw what an example 'comment' object looks like. Note you have two typo's bind-data instead of data-bind.

Comment: Thanks! - Right now a comment looks like this: 

{text: String, src: String, isImage: Boolean, src: String, score: Number}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix the typo's you code should work. `forEach` should be `foreach`, and `bind-data` should be `data-bind` (unless you made it a custom binding).
Have a look at the example below. When `text` is a falsy value (null, empty string), the node will be hidden, else its value will be visible. This holds true for `observable` properties too.

```js
var m = {
  comments: [
    {text: 'a'},
    {text: ko.observable('') },
    {text: null},
    {text: ko.observable('c')}
  ]
};

ko.applyBindings(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="leftchat" data-bind="foreach: comments" class="chat">
  <div data-bind="text: text, visible: text" class="textcontent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. I hate my self so much right now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this
    `data-bind="text: text, visible: text"`
to this 
    `data-bind="text: $data"`

Also maybe change this 
    `data-bind="forEach: comments"`
to this
    `data-bind="forEach: comments()"`

that should evaluate properly the underlying array (allthough this should be working just fine without the ())

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the response!

So I have changed the ...="text: text" to ...="text: $data" but when I do this it just adds the classic [object Object]. If I try to do ...="text: $data.text it complains once again that it cannot find the function. Any ideas?

Comment: If you could make a fiddle for me, i could give you a proper, working response ^^